# php doesn't disable functions

Tags: php

I call php from the commandline, with the -c argument to load another php.ini file, like this:

```
php -c my_ini_file.ini test.php
```

So in `disabled_functions` I added the `echo` function.

In test.php, echo works, and I don't know why. `phpinfo()` shows echo as a disabled function.

Comment: why would you even want to disable echo?

Comment: @Dagon: One reason I could think of would be if the script is executed by a Cron job, then anything that is echo'ed may get sent to postfix and start flooding emails or eating up disk space (if postfix isn't set up). That's something that happened to me, at least.

Comment: echo isn't even a function...

Comment: @Travesty3 wouldn't writing the script correctly be a better option? This is like suppressing errors rather than fixing them

Comment: @Travesty3: In that case, the answer is to redirect output via command-line, not to try and disable output commands of the script.

Comment: @Dagon: Yes, probably. But what if he wants to use one script that can be used both via Cron job or via a web request (which was my scenario)? I wanted the progress messages to be displayed when called from the web, but not when called via command line. Sure, you could check this with if-statements in the script, but there might be an easier way, which leads to a possible reason for this post.

Comment: @webbiedave: So perhaps that would be a good solution for the OP.

Comment: add and if() clause to output from web but not command line - not rocket science.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Echo](https://www.php.net/echo) is not a function, it is a built-in command. It cannot be disabled.

> echo() is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you are not required to use parentheses with it. echo() (unlike some other language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot always be used in the context of a function. Additionally, if you want to pass more than one parameter to echo(), the parameters must not be enclosed within parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs about [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

> echo() is not actually a function (it is a language construct), so you
> are not required to use parentheses with it. echo() (unlike some other
> language constructs) does not behave like a function, so it cannot
> always be used in the context of a function. Additionally, if you want
> to pass more than one parameter to echo(), the parameters must not be
> enclosed within parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

As the other posters have already mentioned, `echo` is not really a function. Perhaps a solution for you would be to write another PHP script that includes the one you want to execute, but turns output buffering on and never outputs it. Something like:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include("test.php");
    ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Comment: I was actually about to edit my answer to reflect your suggestion, you just beat me to it.  This sounds like the correct way to avoid outputting content.